# Is Bezout identity necessary to prove that every sufficiently large number can be expressed as $a\cdot x+b\cdot y$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let be N a positive integer.

Let be a and b positive integers, with gcd(a,b)=1

Let be x and y be positive integers.

How can it be proven that every sufficiently large N can be expressed as:

$a\cdot x+b\cdot y$.

Is  the Bezout identity needed for proving this fact?

Comment: My opinion would be "essentially yes".

Answer (score 0):

If $\text{gcd}(a, b) = 1$, Bézout's identity says that there are some $x, y \in \mathbb Z$ such that $$ax + by = 1.$$ I think from here it should be clear that if we use $z = Nx$ and $w = Ny$, we obtain $$az + bw = N.$$ Thus this doesn't just work for "sufficiently large" $N$, it works for all $N \geq 1$.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question (and presmably the OP already knows the proof by Bezout)